# Send http request without XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, sockets, http, xmlhttprequest

is there any way to send http request without XMLHttpReqeust? or sending http request with socket programing in browser javascript?

Comment: fetch? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I want to write an online app like postman. so fetch does not work for me because of CORS policy i can't sent request to localhost of everyone.

Comment: Use a server as a proxy for your calls. NodeJS is the way to go to do it fast, clean and async. Thats the only way to avoid CORS ;)

Comment: @MahdyAslamy: *:..because of CORS ..."* - it would be bad if there would be a way to bypass a security measure like CORS just by doing it differently.